# python interpolation on ini keys

Tags: python-3.x, string-interpolation

is there any workaround for python ini interpolation for the keys ?

I have a ini file, where i would like to use a repeated value in my keys.

```
[commands]
java_server_start_startup_restart = command to start the java server
database_server_start_startup_restart = command to start the db server
agent_server_start_startup_restart = agent statup command
```

Interpolation didnt work for me to replace the server_start_startup_restart key.

e.g.,

```
[commands]
name=server_start_startup_restart
java_%(name)s = 
database_%(name)s =
agent_%(name)s =
```

Any workaround or options to achieve the above ?